# Error in python replace. (AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace')

Tags: python, variables

#### Environment

I am using Python 3 and my OS is Windows 7.
I understand that some commands have changed from the transition from python 2.7 to 3 (What I have used).

#### Problem

The variable is temporary but is this:

```
(((((0, 7), 7), 8), 4), 5)
```

Here is the code to get rid of the brackets:

```
randy = randy.replace(")", "")
randy = randy.replace("(", "")
randy = randy.replace(" ", "")
```

When it tries to execute the replace function, I get thrown an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 248, in run_nodebug
File "Criptic.py", line 134, in <module>
randy = randy.replace(")", "")
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

#### Edit:

Here is all of the code:

```
#Import string
import string
import random
#Input user data
text = input("Enter your text to be converted: ")

#Test Print
print("-------------------------")
print("Your text is: ",text)




#Break up all the data
data = list(text)

#Lowercase
count = text.count("a")
count1 = text.count("b")
count2 = text.count("c")
count3 = text.count("d")
count4 = text.count("e")
count5 = text.count("f")
count6 = text.count("g")
count7 = text.count("h")
count8 = text.count("i")
count9 = text.count("j")
count10 = text.count("k")
count11 = text.count("l")
count12 = text.count("m")
count13 = text.count("n")
count14 = text.count("o")
count15 = text.count("p")
count16 = text.count("q")
count17 = text.count("r")
count18 = text.count("s")
count19 = text.count("t")
count20 = text.count("u")
count21 = text.count("v")
count22 = text.count("w")
count23 = text.count("x")
count24 = text.count("y")
count25 = text.count("z")
count26 = text.count("A")

#Uppercase
count27 = text.count("B")
count28 = text.count("C")
count29 = text.count("D")
count30 = text.count("E")
count31 = text.count("F")
count32 = text.count("G")
count33 = text.count("H")
count34 = text.count("I")
count35 = text.count("J")
count36 = text.count("K")
count37 = text.count("L")
count38 = text.count("M")
count39 = text.count("N")
count40 = text.count("O")
count41 = text.count("P")
count42 = text.count("Q")
count43 = text.count("R")
count44 = text.count("S")
count45 = text.count("T")
count46 = text.count("U")
count47 = text.count("V")
count48 = text.count("W")
count49 = text.count("X")
count50 = text.count("Y")
count51 = text.count("Z")

#Other Characters
count52 = text.count(" ")
count53 = text.count("?")
count54 = text.count("@")
count55 = text.count("(")
count56 = text.count(")")
count57 = text.count(".")

#Numbers
count58 = text.count("1")
count59 = text.count("2")
count60 = text.count("3")
count61 = text.count("4")
count62 = text.count("5")
count63 = text.count("6")
count64 = text.count("7")
count65 = text.count("8")
count66 = text.count("9")
count67 = text.count("0")

#Counting how many characters in the sentence
finalcount = count + count1 + count2 + count3 + count4 + count5 + count6 + count7 + count8 + count9  + count10  +   count11  + count12  + count13  + count14 + count15 + count16 + count17 + count18 + count19 + count20 + count21 + count22 + count23 + count24 + count25 + count26 + count27 + count28 + count29 + count31 + count32 + count33 + count34 + count35 + count36 + count37 + count38 + count39 + count40 + count41 + count42 + count43 + count44 + count45 + count46 + count47 + count48 + count49 + count50 + count51 + count52 + count53 + count54 + count55 + count56 + count57 + count58 + count59 + count60 + count61 + count62 + count63 + count64 + count65 + count66 + count67

#Final count of Characters
print("       Chars: ",finalcount)
print("-------------------------")





char = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()?_+-=1234567890           "
charnum = 74 + 11
list(char)

randy = 0
num = 0
while num < finalcount:
    rand = random.randrange(1,9)
    randy = randy,rand
    finalcount = finalcount - 1
    if rand == 1:
    print(text[finalcount],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],",")
if rand == 2:
    print(char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],text[finalcount],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],",")
if rand == 3:
    print(char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],text[finalcount],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],",")
if rand == 4:
    print(char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],text[finalcount],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],",")
if rand == 5:
    print(char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],text[finalcount],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],",")
if rand == 6:
    print(char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],text[finalcount],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],",")
if rand == 7:
    print(char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],text[finalcount],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],",")
if rand == 8:
    print(char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],text[finalcount],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],",")
if rand == 9:
   print(char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],char[random.randrange(0,charnum)],text[finalcount],",")


randy = randy.replace(")", "")
randy = randy.replace("(", "")
randy = randy.replace(" ", "")

print("-------------------------")
print("::::::::Completed::::::::")
print("-------------------------")
print(randy)
print("-This is your code unlock key. Without this code it will not decript!!!! ")
print("-------------------------")
```

Comment: Only strings have a `replace` method. Maybe you have to define your `((((...)` thingy as string? Tuple: `randy = (((((0, 7), 7), 8), 4), 5)`, string: `randy = "(((((0, 7), 7), 8), 4), 5)"`

Comment: @James Dyson: Strings are defined like in most other languages. With double or single quotes.

Comment: But I am not setting the varaible.....The program does

Comment: The program only does what you tell it. And *you* set the variable, here: `    rand = random.randrange(1,9)
    randy = randy,rand`.

Comment: (Your problems aren't Python 3 specific, btw, so I added a plain Python tag).

Comment: What the hell is up with this code, lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a tuple (a sort of list) of numbers, and you want to make that a string. You can't replace the brackets, they aren't a part of the variable, they are just a part of its representation.

Instead you should use `join()` and `str()`

```
 result = " ".join(str(x) for x in randy)
```

However, this probably will not give the right result either, as it is a nested list of tuples. You probably mean: `randy = randy + (rand,)` instead if `randy = randy,rand`.

Comment: Thank you very much...But this came up: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Home\AISS\Criptic.py", line 112, in <module>
    randy = randy + (rand,)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

Comment: @James Dyson: The way to say "Thank you" on Stackoverflow is to click the up arrow to the left of the answers you found helpful. :-) Click the Checkbox on the answer you found most helpful to select it as the "most correct" answer. That way other people with the same problem as you can learn too.

Comment: @James Dyson: Ah. So it's not a tuple, it's a list. In that case you do `randy.append(rand)`. You also need to make sure that `randy` is a list from the beginning like this: `randy = [0]`.

Comment: Oh, right, you need points even to upvote. I forgot that. OK, ignore it. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
randy = randy,rand
```

This notation creates a tuple of two elements, tuples do not have a method called `replace`.

If you just want to concatenate the numbers into a list representation separated by commas, you could do this in your loop:

```
randy = []
num = 0
while num < finalcount:
    rand = random.randrange(1,9)
    randy.append(rand)
```

Then you remove the `replace` lines, and instead do this

```
randy = ",".join(randy)
```

to get a string that has the values separated by commas.

You should maybe add the output that you would like to get to your question, because at the moment it's not quite clear what you want to do exactly.

Comment: The output I would like to get is this: 4,5,3,5,2,5 (Example)

Answer (score 1):

```
exam_st_date = (11, 12, 2014)
# Sample Output : The examination will start from : 11 / 12 / 2014

newtup = str(exam_st_date).replace(',', ' /')


print(newtup)
```

look at mine example should give you some results

Answer (score -2):

To delete a list of characters, you could use the string's **translate** method:

```
import string
name = "(((((0, 7), 7), 8), 4), 5)"
table = string.maketrans( '', '', )
print name.translate(table,"()")
```